# How to create ui elements dynamically? Andorid studio, kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How I can create radioButton or something like this by pressing a button? For example:
If I press a button `addElement` then creating `radioButton` in `LinearLayout` with specified prefix.
So like `radioButton.id("prefixId").add("DefaultLayout")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `View.generateViewId()` method automatically creates a unique view ID. However, if you want to assign an ID yourself, you should be sure the ID you specify is unique.

```
private lateinit var linearLayout: LinearLayout
private lateinit var addButton: Button
private var counter = 0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout)
    addButton = findViewById(R.id.button)

    addButton.setOnClickListener {
        addRadioButton()
    }
}

private fun addRadioButton() {
    val radioButton = RadioButton(this)

    //radioButton.id = counter // you can set id yourself if u want
    radioButton.id = View.generateViewId() // for create unique id

    radioButton.text = "defaultLayout $counter"

    val layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )

    linearLayout.addView(radioButton, layoutParams)

    counter++
}
```